# how to use selenium to click 'checkout' button?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The html is as followed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsAqg.png)

I have tried multiple methods like driver.find_element_by_css_selector and others. None worked.please help

Comment: more details, please; What is the exact code you're using, which driver. What error are to seeing?

Comment: Currently, there isn't enough information to provide any help. Please [put the `html` in the question, as image links go stale and image sharing sites are blocked for some users](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, what selectors have you tried? When you say "None worked," what does that mean, did you get exceptions? Did nothing happen?

Comment: So I am using chromedriver on python. I am trying to achieve the auto-checkout feature on this site: http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/z4fqw32ih/n7g4xp63n
And the problem is I have been trying to use 'find_element_by_css_selector' and 'find_element_by_xpath' and none worked or might be because I do not know how to make use of these since I am not familiar with html forms. Is there anything I should do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more information, try to use XPATH and `.click()`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="button checkout"]').click()
```